# Why my WorldOutput trun all hdr map to one-colored

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I want to use custom .hdr file as enviornment map, I do this:
[image]

as you can see, my env is no image but one-color(now is a gray, when I change hdr file, it change with the file), why?

Comment: You used an _Image Texture_ node instead of an _Environment Texture_ node. Always use _Environment Texture_ for HDRI's.

Comment: thank you, sorry for so silly question.

Comment: @Z.Haw By the way, I sometimes experience that when I somehow messed up the _Environment Texture_ so that it doesn't work although the node setup looks correct, I have to open up the HDRI file again with the open dialogue. Just reloading via Alt+R doesn't help.